# EC2 Ubuntu images for local usage

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtualization

Ubuntu provides [virtual images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/) that are used by Amazon EC2. They can be started locally e.g. by running:

> qemu -fda precise-server-cloudimg-i386-floppy -hda
>   precise-server-cloudimg-i386.img

Question: are there pros/cons of using these images instead of creating own ones from ISO files?

Comment: Any specific reason you wanna do that ?

Comment: It's already created for me ;) Also it might have some more or less standard configuration and if people were working with EC2, they might feel comfortable using such image.

Comment: Well, unless you are developing something in about Linux, for me, both the images are same.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Started with Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC?action=show&redirect=Eucalyptus)

Note: Starting with 11.10 (oneiric), Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud is replaced by Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure, which is based on [OpenStack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openstack).

---

You're getting a package of "enterprise grade" management and infrastructure tools. My guess is that they are not installed or included with the traditional installation media. Check it out, see if you need any if it and base your decision on that.